# Get back from the Assigned Campaign to my campaign Area

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I Create and assign one campaign to another Team-mate in "**wait for approval**".IF my team-mate is "Approved" that assigned campaign.At that time **how to i get back that same campaign  to my campaign area with approved status in CRM 2011**.How to Do this ,which means what is the work flow? Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a workflow running on change of status, which checks if status is now "Approved" and re-assigns the Campaign. In the scenario as described you would simply re-assign the Campaign back to the user who created it.

Being more flexible, you could add a custom lookup field / relationship to the Campaign entity. When a Campaign is assigned or status changes, check if status is now "Waiting approval". If so, store the "Last modified by" user in the custom field. Then when you do the reassign back again, do it to this user, not the created by user.

Comment: Thanks For ur reply please tell me more clearly because am new to this

Comment: That was as clear as I could be for such a vague question. You might want to try re-wording to outline like this:

Comment: What are you doing already, What do you want to do next, Ideally say what you have tried as well. There's also no obvious reason you can't just do this by having the user assign it back again, so you may want to explain why that does not work for you